# Determining Whether a User is in a Specific Location in the Background

Tags: ios, core-location, google-places-api, background-process, passbook

In an iOS app that I'm working on, I need to be able to determine whether the user is in an establishment even when the app is closed. The basic premise is that the user will select a location(McDonald's, Walmart, a bank, etc) and then whenever they walk into that chosen location the app will alert them and provide a call to action(can't really go into specifics about what the action is). Right now, I'm using the Google Places API and finding the nearest business to the user's current location using Core Location. This works, but only when the app is open. I'm wondering if there is any way I can utilize Passbook for this, since it is able to determine when a user walks into a location. However, I'm not sure I can do this since I don't own any of the establishments the user might select. Any suggestions on frameworks, methods,etc for doing this? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If the locations you're wanting to monitors are limited, you can use :

```
CLLocationManager
  - startMonitoringForRegion:
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringForRegion:

"An app can register up to 20 regions at a time."

Answer (score 0):

Important point. When the app is closed, there is nothing you can do, until it is launched by the user (clicking the app icon) or when it is launched by the system (e.g. when there is voIP requirements).

You may refer to the app being in background (it was launched by the user and then the home button was clicked)

For the functionality you want, you could implement the UIApplicationDelegate methods to activate and deactivate the location manager in background.

e.g. You can combine a NSTimer that fires each interval to activate the position and then stop the location manager, to avoid consuming battery

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60 target:self selector:@selector(launchLocationManager) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]
}

- (void) launchLocationManager {
    myLocationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    myLocationManager.delegate = self;
    [myLocationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{
    //report location
    [myLocationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

}
```

Comment: If you start monitoring for region changes, you can perform background processing without the user launching the app.